# How can I create a common Id for multiple tables?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm new to learning PostgreSQL, so I appreciate any and all help.

I'm trying to create multiple tables. I want the primary key for the table to be a combination of a district column + school column.

Here's an example of how my tables are set up:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
school VarChar(50), 
division VARCHAR(40), 
otherattribute (varchar70),
 etc.); 

CREATE TABLE table2(
school VarChar(50), 
division VARCHAR(40), 
otherattribute (varchar70), 
etc.);
```

I want to create another table that's along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE assignID(randomId INTEGER, school VarChar(50), division VARCHAR(40));
```

Then I want to replace any primary key that is a school and division combo in any of my tables with the randomId that is assigned to that school and division combo. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you have compound varchar/varchar PKs in various places and you want to switch them to a single numeric PK while maintaining data integrity?

Comment: Basically! I think I found a solution though, I posted it in my main post. It seems to work. Could you check it for me if you get a chance and let me know if I missed anything?

Comment: You might want to have an `(id, school, division)` table and then FK the other tables that one too. That gives your school/division an existence of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, here's my code for it.

1. Created a table1 with the serial ID and the other attributes (school and division) I wanted to attach the serial ID too.
2. I created all of the tables I wanted to use, I added the attributes(school and div) that I wanted the serial ID tied too and then I added columns, but not the ID column itself.
3. I populated all of the relations with the data from excel spreadsheets.
4. I added an ID column to all of tables that were not table 1.
5. I ran this script:

   ```
   UPDATE tables SET ID=table1.ID
   FROM table1
   WHERE tables.schoolName = table1.schoolName
   AND tables.divisionName = table1.divisionName;
   ```

   This added the serial number that was tied to a school and division combo in table1 to any table with a similar combination.
6. Then I dropped the school and division columns for all my tables.

I know it's not the most optimized solution, but it was the only one I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you thinking about making an intelligent choice for your primary key. How you choose primary key values is probably the single most important factor in the future usability of your database.

What you are really doing here is a process called "database normalization". Here is a good introduction (aimed at beginners) to some of the vital central concepts in data modeling: http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. I added the solution I came up with to my main post as an edit. Could you check it out for me? It seems to work, but I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Seems like you accomplished what you wanted to... good on you for figuring it out.